# Error secuencia if en python pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Espero que alguien me ayude, estoy comenzando con python y tengo este problema, no sé en qué me estoy equivocando pero mi código tira el siguiente error:

```
File "C:/Users/WIN10.DESKTOP-IECJ1FI/.PyCharmEdu2018.3/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 30, in <module>
    if int(cantidad_cuotas <= 3):
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error está en  `cantidad_cuotas = print(int(input(...)))`, ese `print` sobra, **`cantidad_cuotas` es el retorno de `print`, `None` y no un entero**, de ahí el error. Luego `if int(cantidad_cuotas<=3)`, debe ser solo `if cantidad_cutas <= 3`, lo mismo para el `elif`, esto en realidad no causa ningún error, simplemente haces un casting de un `bool` a `int` innecesario totalmente. Además, sobra el casting a `str` en los `input (input(str("blabla")))` basta con `input("blabla")`.

Comment: 2 cosas. La primera el error, en la comparación `if int(cantidad_cuotas <= 3):` la variable `cantidad_cuotas` es `None` por lo que no se puede comparar un "entero" (`int`) con un `None`. Lo segundo que veo es la sentencia `cantidad_cuotas =print(int(input('Ingresa la cantidad de cuotas: ')))`, en la que si quitas el `print` ya te debería funcionar. Los `str` de los `input` también sobran. suerte!!

Comment: Por otro lado, no debes colocar código en una imagen, se hace difícil de leer (especialmente en dispositivos móviles) y de reproducir. Además no indexa para búsquedas futuras. En su lugar, copia el código como texto y luego lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor para formatearlo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo por que haces `if int(cantidad_cuotas <= 3)` y no solo haces `if (cantidad_decuotas <= 3)`.  Lo otro raro que veo es el print que haces en la asignacion de `cantidad_cuotas`. Después de eso no veo fallas.

Comment: Acabo de modificarlo, y me sigue arrojando el mismo error... :/

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo en forma de texto y no de imagen, asi puedo testear tu codigo?